# Http PostAsJsonAsync getting null parameter (DTO)

Tags: c#, post, client-server, httpclient, dto

I am trying to pass a DTO class object to my server but the object is being send null

DTO:

```
public class FileSettings
{
    public int SetID { get; set; }
    public int RunID { get; set; }
    public int FileID { get; set; }
}
```

Client:

```
string URL = "http://localhost:9000";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

FileSettings data = new FileSettings();
data.SetID = setID;
data.RunID = runID;
data.FileID = fileID;

HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
// Add an Accept header for JSON format.
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/output/ApplyFileRule", content);
```

Server:

```
public void ApplyFileRule([FromBody] FileSettings data)
{
    var runID = data.RunID;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is data the class name or the instance of the class.  You need to use the instance of the class that contains the data.

Comment: Its the instance, I am initialize it on the client: FileSettings data = new FileSettings(); and then sending it as httpcontent

Comment: To make sure data is being sent use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Then you can determine if error is in the client or server.

Comment: So I was tracking the request (using wireshark) and I notice I was sending the: "Value":["application/json; charset=utf-8"]. My guess is that since I am using PostAsJsonAsync theres no really use to JsonConvert before and put into a httpcontent. So I sent directly the data and everything worked fine: client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/output/ResetTipifications", data). Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these:

```
FileSettings data = new FileSettings();
FileSettings.SetID = setID;
FileSettings.RunID = runID;
FileSettings.FileID = fileID;

HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

To this:

```
FileSettings data = new FileSettings();
data.SetID = setID;
data.RunID = runID;
data.FileID = fileID;

HttpContent content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Comment: that was actually a mistake from me while copying the code! That part is wrong and your change is correct. Though it didnt solve the problem. The problem was actually the fact that I am using PostAsJsonAsync and still doing a JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data). So if you change your answer I can accept it as correct :)

Comment: Updated... also I'd recommend taking a look at Flurl.  Makes for clean testable coding.  https://flurl.dev/